# Encrypted in java (Android) failing in python AES decryption

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes, pkcs#7

I am trying to decrypt a java AES encrypted code into python script but it's failing to decrypt completely, means some of initial data does not decrypted but rest of data decrypted fine. Below is python code -

```
decryptor = Cipher(
            algorithms.AES(self._encryption_key),
            modes.CBC(initialization_vector),
            self._backend
        ).decryptor()
        plaintext_padded = decryptor.update(ciphertext)
        try:
            plaintext_padded += decryptor.finalize()
        except ValueError:
            raise InvalidToken
        unpadder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder()

        unpadded = unpadder.update(plaintext_padded)
        try:
            unpadded += unpadder.finalize()
        except ValueError:
            raise InvalidToken
```

And below is my java code that can ecnrypt and decrypt successfully it's own generated cipher to plain and vice versa.

```
aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
.
.
static SecretKey generateSecretKey() {

        SecretKeyFactory pbeKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8bit");
        SecretKey secretKey;
        try {
            SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
            byte[] salt = new byte[32];
            rand.nextBytes(salt);
            // WORK-AROUND change rand.nextInt(2048) to rand.nextInt(2047) + 1 to genterate 1-2048;
            int iterationCount = rand.nextInt(2047) + 1;
            KeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(new String(rand.generateSeed(24)).toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, 256);
            SecretKey pbeKey = pbeKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(pbeKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return secretKey;
    }

    static SymmetricEncryptionEntry symmetricEncrypt(SecretKey key, String data) {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        SymmetricEncryptionEntry entry;
        try {
            byte[] iv = generateIv(cipher.getBlockSize());
            IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            entry = new SymmetricEncryptionEntry(cipherText , iv);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return entry;
    }

    private static byte[] generateIv(int length) {
        byte[] b = new byte[length];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(b);

        return b;
    }
```

Below is the real plain text and decrypted plain text -

**expected by python decryption**

```
b'{"auth_key":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImZhMWQ3NzBlZWY5ZWFhNjU0MzY1ZGE5MDhjNDIzY2NkNzY4ODkxMDUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vY2hhdHEtc3RhZ2luZyIsImF1ZCI6ImNoYXRxLXN0YWdpbmciLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NzExMjM5NDcsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJyQ3N0aTBoMEczVUZmVWk2Q1oxYjNJOEJmOVIyIiwic3ViIjoickNzdGkwaDBHM1VGZlVpNkNaMWIzSThCZjlSMiIsImlhdCI6MTU3MTIwMjY4OSwiZXhwIjoxNTcxMjA2Mjg5LCJwaG9uZV9udW1iZXIiOiIrODQxMjM0NTY3ODIiLCJmaXJlYmFzZSI6eyJpZGVudGl0aWVzIjp7InBob25lIjpbIis4NDEyMzQ1Njc4MiJdfSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6InBob25lIn19.0OCskQkPKq5yxku02PuBgoZMFHgMfZBVPptQaVExrWYRDrEM3uUwDrDXAWiqA6L9i54fg_7dfWBwnPvQ71g4Lzsft60_JycS0-C_kSlCBxVSlX5J8WDTwNGm6p5-QDxN2bU9fwglzmggMst-4A3tLlPLQRnttuishFKhgr40ABHX8tksNfbs626YhTiwY6vD6_Gn0k7X7jh1HsHAUUcnPZq2tCXRFUKNDmF_4lC6vc7-Cs5zHpIlKtaAXoQBRe9HYsEvYfK2tOey8T_3mDC_Eh36fcve6HCOQBt9EtFPRIUcKZgFDWPoG70t-ABk66Lr2BjejbOsBBnA9R7492t6Sg","correlation_id":"1fb572ff331346b7","user_id":"rCsti0h0G3UFfUi6CZ1b3I8Bf9R2"}'
```

**Received by python decryption**

```
b'\xae\xfa\x9c\xb3\x8c+\x17\xfeI\xc9\xb8\x0b\x0e@\xac\rhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImZhMWQ3NzBlZWY5ZWFhNjU0MzY1ZGE5MDhjNDIzY2NkNzY4ODkxMDUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vY2hhdHEtc3RhZ2luZyIsImF1ZCI6ImNoYXRxLXN0YWdpbmciLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NzExMjM5NDcsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJyQ3N0aTBoMEczVUZmVWk2Q1oxYjNJOEJmOVIyIiwic3ViIjoickNzdGkwaDBHM1VGZlVpNkNaMWIzSThCZjlSMiIsImlhdCI6MTU3MTIwMjY4OSwiZXhwIjoxNTcxMjA2Mjg5LCJwaG9uZV9udW1iZXIiOiIrODQxMjM0NTY3ODIiLCJmaXJlYmFzZSI6eyJpZGVudGl0aWVzIjp7InBob25lIjpbIis4NDEyMzQ1Njc4MiJdfSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6InBob25lIn19.0OCskQkPKq5yxku02PuBgoZMFHgMfZBVPptQaVExrWYRDrEM3uUwDrDXAWiqA6L9i54fg_7dfWBwnPvQ71g4Lzsft60_JycS0-C_kSlCBxVSlX5J8WDTwNGm6p5-QDxN2bU9fwglzmggMst-4A3tLlPLQRnttuishFKhgr40ABHX8tksNfbs626YhTiwY6vD6_Gn0k7X7jh1HsHAUUcnPZq2tCXRFUKNDmF_4lC6vc7-Cs5zHpIlKtaAXoQBRe9HYsEvYfK2tOey8T_3mDC_Eh36fcve6HCOQBt9EtFPRIUcKZgFDWPoG70t-ABk66Lr2BjejbOsBBnA9R7492t6Sg","correlation_id":"1fb572ff331346b7","user_id":"rCsti0h0G3UFfUi6CZ1b3I8Bf9R2"}'
```

**Basically, the beginning is messed up:**

```
{"auth_key":"eyJ != \xae\xfa\x9c\xb3\x8c+\x17\xfeI\xc9\xb8\x0b\x0e@\xac\r
```

Let me know in comment if I missed anything in question :-)

Comment: These are typical symptoms of a wrong Initialization Vector. Make sure that  `initialization_vector` have the exact same value as what you got from `generateIv(..)`

Comment: I am sending the same IV as RSA encrypted to python and it's decrypted at the python end.

Comment: Some definitions/implementations are missing in the Java-code: What is `getInstance()`, `getInstance().pbeKeyFactory`, `getInstance().aesCipher`, `SymmetricEncryptionEntry`? Is `getInstance().aesCipher` identical to `aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding")`? `SunJCE` doesn't know `PKCS7Padding`, do you use `BouncyCastle`? Although some things can be guessed, it remains guessing. Post minimal, complete and consistent code please.

Comment: @Topaco I updated my code a bit, SymmetricEncryptionEntry class is just my defined class, I just saved sipher bytes and IV in it's property  so that i can send to server.

Comment: The counterpart to the `generateSecretKey`-method of the Java-code is missing in the Python-code. Probably the respective part was merely not posted, because the decryption seems to work apart from the beginning. By the way: _I am sending the same IV as RSA encrypted to python and it's decrypted at the python end._: The IV does not need to be kept secret, so there is no need for an encryption of the IV.

Comment: If I execute the `symmetricEncrypt`-method in the Java-code and apply the key _used_ here as well as the IV _generated_ here in the Python-code, the decryption is _successful_! So you obviously have to make a mistake transferring the data from Java- to Python-code. As already mentioned in the comment, a wrong beginning with otherwise correct decryption is characteristic for a bad IV. You should post a concrete example, i.e. input for the `symmetricEncrypt`-method in the Java-code: plaintext and key (hex), output of the Java-code: ciphertext and IV (both hex), output of the Python-code.